# React can't find 3rd party scripts I've included

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to work through the [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) and have run into a stumbling block. I have the following HTML

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./src/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css" />
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.1/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.1/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/jquery@3.1.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/remarkable@1.6.2/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="src/index.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div id="sidebar" class="col s3">
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="col s9">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/babel">

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

With the following javascript file.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

var data = [
  { id: 1, author: "Pete Hunt", text: "This is the 1st comment" },
  { id: 2, author: "Jordan Walke", text: "This is *the 3rd* comment." },
  { id: 3, author: "John Doe", text: "This comment is stupid." }
];

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return { data: [] };
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({ data: data });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList data={this.state.data} />
        <CommentForm />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
          {comment.text}
        </Comment>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="commentForm">
        I'm a Form.
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Comment = React.createClass({
  rawMarkup: function() {
    var markdown = new Remarkable();
    var rawMarkup = markdown.render(this.props.children.toString());
    return { __html: rawMarkup };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="comment">
        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
          {this.props.author}
        </h2>
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentBox data={data} />,
  document.getElementById('content')
);
```

I'm using the content created from the [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) NPM module. When I run the app, I'm told:

- Remarkable isn't defined
- $ is not defined

Both JQuery and Remarkable are included in my HTML file, and I made sure to put them before my `index.js` script. Why is it that the app can't find the Types? Is this a React issue, or a Node,js issue? I'm a bit new to web-dev so I'm not sure which component is at fault here or what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: I think your script runs faster than others loaded. You need to await DOMContentLoaded

Comment: How do I await that? The tutorial doesn't show my needing to do that, which is odd

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your scripts are loading asynchronously. Waiting for all your scripts to be loadded with jQuery...

```
(function($){$(function(){

  // your react app code here...

})})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ah, so this lead me to ask "should jquery and react be used together?". After some reading it sounds like you should use one or the other; not both at the same time. Is that your recommendation too, on a new greenfield project?

Comment: jQuery is known to be used mainly to manipulate the DOM directly, which is the opposite of working with React, because React uses its own 'virtual' DOM to stay in sync with the 'real' DOM (the one jQuery manipulates).

But!! jQuery can be used for many many other things other than DOM manipulation. It has some syntactic sugar for stuff like "wait for the DOM ready", "send this xhr request", etc. You can achieve the same behavior without jQuery, but you'll have to write a little more code.

Some handy code snippets here http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: And so would you use something like Flux then instead of jquery/Ajax to talk to a server?